# How to reduce output of git grep

Tags: git

I search within a repository by **git grep** by this way:

```
git rev-list --all | xargs git grep -lP --no-index regexp
```

I expected that in the output there will be only revisions of files which match to regexp expression, but I recieve all revisions, even that in which matched files have not been changed. For instance, there is a file named README.md and it has been changed twice in 1 and 4 revisions. However when I search by **git grep** I also recived revisions of 2 and 3 where README.md has not been changed.

I tried to find some options of **git grep** command to do what I want, but found nothing.

Very appreciate any help!

Comment: What is your intent here, to find all instances of a given search term across the entire history of the project?

Comment: yes, I have to find some special terms in all our repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have yet to answer [meagar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822363/how-to-reduce-output-of-git-grep#comment92561781_52822363), but it's worth pointing out a few things anyway:

- Each commit is a full snapshot of the entire source.  That is, each commit contains a complete tree of all of the files.  Someone ran `git commit`; this froze all files in whatever form they had in the index at that time.  That became the commit's snapshot.
- Running `git grep` makes Git search through some sort(s) of tree(s) of files, searching for files that contain regular expressions.

By giving `git grep` a list of commits, you are telling it to find every match in every file of every such tree.  So *of course* if commits A, B, and C contain files that match, Git will tell you about the files in A, B, and C.

---

Perhaps your goal is to take every *pair* of commits, and do something with them.  For instance, suppose the repository has exactly three non-merge commits, `A`, `B`, and `C`:

```
A  <-B  <-C   <--master
```

Commit `A` has no parent (it's a root commit), so for pairing purposes Git will insert an empty commit—one that has no files—in front of `A`.  We can call this ε.  We can then have Git compare:

- ε vs `A`: all files are added
- `A` vs `B`: some files are changed
- `B` vs `C`: some files are changed

We could do this manually, one pair at a time, but there is a way to automate it: `git log -p` does that.  In each of these *change-sets*, there will be some lines of some files shown.  We can have `git log` *search* these change-sets as well, using `git log -S` or `git log -G`.

These two searches—`-S` and `-G`—are similar, but not identical.  `-G` takes an ordinary regular expression (a la `git grep`); `-S` takes a string by default, but can be told that its argument is a regular expression using `--pickaxe-regex`.

In general, both tell `git log` that it should show the *commit* (at all) if the *change-set* contains the given expression (but see the next bit).  You can therefore leave out the `-p` if you're just interested in the commit itself.  If you want to see the changes made *by* that commit, include the `-p`:

```
git log -p -G regex
```

The other difference between `-S` and `-G`, besides that `-S` takes a string by default, is that `-S` looks at the *count* of *occurrences* of matches.  Hence if you search for a particular word, and a patch changes the line that *contains* the word but doesn't *add* or *remove* the word, `-G` will show the commit while `-S` won't.

---

If you're trying to see who made some particular line(s) of some particular file(s) look the way they do, `git diff` is not the right tool, but `git grep` and `git log` are wrong too.  Instead, use `git annotate` or `git blame` (these are essentially the same command; see [the `git annotate` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-annotate)).

Comment: I think the answer is no, but is there a version of `git log -G` that shows commits and filenames without showing commit details (changes)?

Comment: @zzxyz: it's not the most convenient format, but `git log -G <regex> --pretty=format:%H --name-only` does the trick: you get the hash ID, a newline, the list of file names, and a blank line. Pipe through something like awk to make the format more useful, e.g.: `git log -G lockfile --pretty=format:%H --name-only | awk '!R { cid=$0; R=1; next } /^$/ { R=0; next } { print cid, $0 }'`

Comment: torek...that's beautiful...enough to pipe further along, which is occasionally critical.  Thanks!

Comment: torek, much thanks for such detail answer! Now I understand much more at git! I have tried the same git-log options `--pretty=format:%H --name-only`. Also thanks for very useful last command, I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

```
git log -p -G regexp
```

You can perform a grep on the output of this since it shows the entire patch for a file&commit that has a change of your regex.

You can also use `git log --cc -G regexp` and maybe should vs. what I've become used to, which is technically "patch" output.  They only vary slightly.

and fwiw I typically use `| grep -C 6 '^commit'` if I'm only interested in filenames & commit versions.

Comment: @ambrous - no problem.  It's funny, I started with almost the exact same thing you were doing when I tried to figure this out the first time, too, which is why I was pretty sure I knew what you were trying to do.